# createBottomTabNavigator keep stackes mounted

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I have an top level SwitchNavigator with two stacks (AuthStack and MainStack)
MainStack contains the stack of an logged user.
When I try to switch from one screen to other it's fine, but if I start an action that change the state of the current screen, if I leave and then come back the state keeps the same, it's like the screens was not unmounted when I switch between others.

Working example: https://snack.expo.io/HJrslFk34

Try to move to settings, click on "add" and then switch between the screens, the state keeps the same and screens were not being unmounted

```
const MainStack = createBottomTabNavigator(
        {
            [homeDrawerLabel]: {
                screen: HomeNavigator,
                navigationOptions: {
                    tabBarLabel: homeDrawerLabel,
                    tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
                        <Ionicons
                            name="ios-bookmarks"
                            size={25}
                            color={tintColor}
                        />
                    ),
                },
            },
            [calendarDrawerLabel]: {
                screen: CalendarNavigator,
                navigationOptions: {
                    tabBarLabel: calendarDrawerLabel,
                    tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
                        <Ionicons
                            name="ios-bookmarks"
                            size={25}
                            color={tintColor}
                        />
                    ),
                    headerLayoutPreset: "center",
                },
            },
            [messagesDrawerLabel]: {
                screen: MessagesNavigator,
                navigationOptions: {
                    tabBarLabel: messagesDrawerLabel,
                    tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
                        <Ionicons
                            name="ios-bookmarks"
                            size={25}
                            color={tintColor}
                        />
                    ),
                },
            },
            [notificationsDrawerLabel]: {
                screen: NotificationsNavigator,
                navigationOptions: {
                    tabBarLabel: notificationsDrawerLabel,
                    tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
                        <IconNavigatorWithBadge
                            badgeCount={3}
                            name="md-checkmark-circle"
                            size={25}
                            color={tintColor}
                        />
                    ),
                },
            },
            EditProfile: { screen: EditProfile },
            [paymentDrawerLabel]: {
                screen: PaymentsNavigator,
                navigationOptions: {
                    tabBarLabel: paymentDrawerLabel,
                    tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
                        <Ionicons
                            name="ios-bookmarks"
                            size={25}
                            color={tintColor}
                        />
                    ),
                },
            },
        },
        {
            tabBarOptions: {
                activeTintColor: "#29C2AF",
                inactiveTintColor: "rgba(41, 194, 175, 0.4)",
                style: {
                    height: 60,
                    paddingVertical: 10,
                    borderTopColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.2)",
                    shadowColor: "#000",
                    shadowOffset: {
                        width: 2,
                        height: 5,
                    },
                    shadowOpacity: 0.75,
                    shadowRadius: 3.84,
                    elevation: 7,
                },
            },
            headerMode: "none",
            headerLayoutPreset: "center",
        },
    );

    const AppNavigator = createSwitchNavigator(
        {
            AuthStack: AuthStack,
            Main: MainStack,
        },
        {
            headerMode: "none",
            initialRouteName: "AuthStack",
        }
    );

    const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

Comment: To clarify, are you expecting the tabs to unmount when switching between them or are you having an issue with the SwitchNavigator not unmouting the previous view?

Comment: I'm expecting to the tabs unmount when switch

Comment: Ah - that is not how the tab navigators work for react navigation, please see the answer below for more details.

Answer (score 2):

With React Navigation, Tab Navigator views are not unmounted when switching between tabs. You can see the details about the lifecycle in react-navigation in their documentation here: [Navigation lifecycle - Example scenario](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-lifecycle.html#example-scenario), the important part being here:

> We start on the HomeScreen and navigate to DetailsScreen. Then we use the tab bar to switch to the SettingsScreen and navigate to ProfileScreen. After this sequence of operations is done, **all 4 of the screens are mounted**!

If you want to know and act on the active tab, what you will be looking for are the focus/blur events outlined [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-events.html)

Comment: I see, but there's a way to reset the component state when a willFocus/didFocus is triggered? I just want to refresh the inputs or any kind of state that I have

Comment: @JoãoVictor Use `setState()` during a willFocus/didFocus and pass in an initial state